# What is the meaning of "boot" in "Spring-Boot" title

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know and understand, And have read a lot about

> **Spring-Boot**

, and how it's improving the use of Spring framework.

But I'm still not sure what's the actual meaning of

> **"Boot"**

in the context of this title.

It's mean that it's kick off Spring to more high place, or it gives you boots to walk with Spring? Or something else.

Didn't found any explanation about that.

I will be glad for an answer.

(the source of the name

> **"Spring"**

is also interesting )

Comment: I believe it is short for [Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) (as well as being a pithy short name in and of itself).

Comment: yes, spring, the first framework which is so complex that it became a meta-framework (spring boot)

Answer (score 6):

Spring is a Framework of Java. Spring-Boot combined means Bootstrapping a Spring Application.

It simply means You have to configure your application to the bare minimum to get your Application up and Running.

Spring boot takes an 'Opinionated' view of what a basic Application should have.

Spring boot bootstraps your Application in such a way that it contains almost everything needed to run a full application.

Basically, Spring-Boot is a way to make a Spring Application up and running without a lot of configuration and boiler-plate code.